# CSS hide element in bootstrap4 `card` when the columns are small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a grid layout of [cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/). up to 12 image cards per row, naturally, the cards get quite small with 12 cards and I would like to show just the image in this case, however, when the row has a length of 6 I would like to show the description as well.

I tried the `d-none d-sm-block` utilities but they are defined by the viewport, not by the size of the card in the column

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card mb-5 border-0">
      <a class="link" href="{{pathFor 'thing.page' id=_id}}" >
        <img src="{{getImage}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          text 1
        </p>
        <p class="card-text">
          text 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`col-md-4` I change dynamically depending on the amount of columns the user has set.

What I want is that `card-text` hides when there are 12 columns (smaller card) but not if there are 5 columns!

here is a picture: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixjz1039fwylowu/Screenshot%202020-04-22%2000.00.54.png?dl=0

and here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixjz1039fwylowu/Screenshot%202020-04-22%2000.00.54.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you using .row and the .col-{size} classes to define your rows? Or are you just letting them lay out how they want?

Comment: I tried to clarify @Nieminen

Comment: @ThomasTraum there are two answers available, please give feedback on it so, we know your problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 1):

### Check these card i am using grid for 12 column for all device view large, small, extra small (mobile) device and also use d-none class for display:none for all device.

> Now, you can see and use whenever you want to do it, I just have an
>   example, how can you use it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
     
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-3">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 5</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 6</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 7</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 8</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 9</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 11</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
          <div class="card">
          <p class="text-center mt-3">hello</p><hr />
          <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none text-center">card 12</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

### Check these card i am using grid for 12, 6, column for all device view large, small, extra small (mobile) device and also use d-none class for display:none for all device.

> Now, you can see and use whenever you want to do it, I just have an
>   example, how can you use it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-xs-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-sm-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-xs-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-sm-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-xs-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-sm-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-xs-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2 d-sm-none">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 11</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 my-xs-2 my-sm-2">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">card 12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this answer is not matched with a question, please update your question else someone gives you downvote.

Comment: please learn how to give an answer on StackOverflow before posting on StackOverflow, learn markup also.

Comment: the point is I dont want to change depending on viewport... I want it to change depending on size of the card.

12 columns => small cards => hide some content

not at all depending on viewport as in responsive

Comment: I forgot to display none, so I edited my code again. Look at the code above, I have made some content as display none or display box as per your requirement i think please check.

Answer (score 0):

It work with `d-block d-lg-none`.

I keep 12 cards in `1200px` and after resolution and keep 6 cards before `1200px`.

If you want to change resolution, you need to replace `lg` in two places.

1st in `col-2 col-lg-1` and second in `d-block d-lg-none`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-2 col-lg-1">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body d-block d-lg-none">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the point is I dont want to change depending on viewport... I want it to change depending on size of the card. 

12 columns => small cards => hide some content, 
4 columsn => big cards => show all the content
not at all depending on viewport as in a responsive design

Comment: how you change your card size, using viewport or else?

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!